# Sweet Home 3D doesn't start 

Tags: 11.04, java

I've recently installed Ubuntu 11.04 and downloaded the "Sweet Home 3D" program from the Software Center. It installed and it shows up as one of the applications when I search for it, but I cannot get it to start at all. Any idea how I can do this or if this is a known issue?

I am using a `Dell Studio 15 1558 laptop` and the `fglrx driver` for my ATI graphics card. But I have a feeling that this problem has nothing to do with hardware or drivers.

Edit:
This is what I get when I type 'sweethome3d' in the terminal:

```
zeiger@ubuntu:~$ sweethome3d
[warning] /usr/bin/sweethome3d: Unable to locate /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/javaws.jar in /usr/share/java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jnlp/UnavailableServiceException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jnlp.UnavailableServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: com.eteks.sweethome3d.SweetHome3D. Program will exit.
zeiger@ubuntu:~$
```

And I installed SweetHome3d using the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Can you try to start the program from the terminal? This will likely help you track down where the software is breaking.

Comment: I think that incompatibility with FGLRX could be a reason, but I am just guessing. As Marco suggested, run Terminal, execute `sweethome3d` and show us output (possibly using http://paste.ubuntu.com/ ) - if there's any.

Comment: The console idea is great, but how have you installed it?. Sweet Home 3D packs it's own jre, I had to grant it run privileges to be able to launch it.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi @jnv @JavierRivera I have updated the question with the information required

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install sun-java6-bin from the Software Centre.

I have Sweet Home installed. When I remove sun-java, SH doesn't launch. When I reinstall it, SH launches.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be that the launch script located in /usr/share/sweethome3d/sweethome3d.sh looks for jre installed on a hardcoded path to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun".

To fix it:

1. On Ubuntu, open terminal and run:

   sudo gedit /usr/share/sweethome3d/sweethome3d.sh
2. Change the line:
   **find_jars /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/javaws.jar** 
   to 
   **find_jars $(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")/lib/javaws.jar**
3. Save the script.
4. Try to run the app!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by *SweetHome3D*, which looks for Sun java files directly.

I put `javaws.jar` from another package as file to 
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/javaws.jar` 
then, the problem seems solved, *SweetHome3D* started.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

1. Downloaded jre-6u27-linux-i586.bin and install it.
2. As root, copy `~/Downloads/jre1.6.0_27/lib/javaws.jar` to `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib`.
3. As root, create a link `ln -s default-java java-6-sun`.
4. Run `sweethome3d`.

It worked at least for me.

Comment: This a quite worse solution than the accepted one. Not only are you using a manual download instead of using repositories, you are copying this over the the already installed version. You can have all kind of fun with this setup if the normal system updates decide to update their java.